# How to get the same behavior in an object when the value is copied to another variable

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

In this console:

[image: Console Image]

When `B` is set to `A` but `A` was destroyed afterwards, `B.b()` throws an error because A is truly undefined.

How can one avoid this?

**PS:** I am aware that I can simply `return this` (or change the function in some way) but that doesn't fulfill my purposes.

**EDIT**: How do I 'localise' and somehow tell javascript that by `A`, I mean `B` even if A is undefined, WITHOUT ALTERING THE FUNCTION ITSELF?

Comment: Could you elaborate your purposes in the question, seeing as `this` keyword is used for precisely that?

Comment: Images are fine, but text is better. Imagine if you couldn't see the image; your text wouldn't make sense. Please include either just text, or both.

Comment: `return this.a` should work

Comment: You could also just change `B.b` to look at `B` instead of `A`. I.e., `B.b = function () { return B.a; };`. But @Anurag's question is a good one; why not avail yourself of the obvious and purpose-built mechanism for this functionality?

Comment: @HereticMonkey,I don't want to change the function.

Comment: @HereticMonkey and everyone else, Can you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60876579/how-to-clone-a-function-but-handle-the-variables-too) out? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the new viewers, if you want to do this without altering the function:

```js
var A = (function() {
  var A = {a: 90, b: function() { return A.a }}; // same object as in the Q
  return A;
})()

console.log(A.b()) // 90

var B = A;
A = undefined;

console.log(B.b()) // Also 90

B.a = 89;
console.log(B.b()) // 89
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change your A to look like the following:

```
let A = {
  a: "a",
  b: function() {
    // change A.a to this.a
    return this.a;
  }
};
```

Right now since it references A when you destroy A Even though B is already equal to A the b method still needs the original A to exist.  Swapping it for `this` will fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks, for your contribution, can you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60876579/how-to-clone-a-function-but-handle-the-variables-too) out as well? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The way the question and example is written that "error" cannot be avoided. `return A.a;` *will* and **SHOULD** be `undefined` based on your example because you are assigning `A = undefined`;

Also, if you are trying to clone an object, there are a couple of other options you should look into like:

1. `let B = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(A));`
2. `let B = Object.assign({}, A);` [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)
3. [Javascript classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)

And maybe check out this answer: [How do I correctly clone a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object)

Comment: Which 'this' are you talking about? :)

Comment: #1 in your list would remove the `b` method altogether... #2 suffers from the same problem as the OP's code, since it copies a reference to the `b` method to `B`.

Comment: Even if I do any of that, as soon as I set `A` to undefined, the same problem occurs, doesn't it?

Comment: Anyway, please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60876579/how-to-clone-a-function-but-handle-the-variables-too) that I asked as well.