# How to refer itself in a function regardless of extenal variable changes?

Tags: javascript

I have a function which has other functions defined:

```
var A = function(n) {
  console.log(n + A.num());
}
A.num = function() {
  return 5;
}
```

I want to change the name to `B` and delete `A`:

```
var B = A;
A = undefined;
```

But, when I do `B()`, It gives an error throws: "Cannot read property 'num' of undefined", which is completely normal and expected.

How do I handle this?

**PS**: Anyone who thinks that changing `A.num()` with `this.num()`, **It will not work**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always refer to the current function using its explicit name (if it has one).

So, change the definition, to name the function, and refer to it using that:

```js
var A = function currentFunction(n) {
  console.log(n + currentFunction.num());
}
A.num = function() {
  return 5;
}

var B = A;
A = undefined;
B(10); //15

console.log(typeof currentFunction) //undefined, function name is local
```

> Note: the abovementioned  approach won't work if the function is named implicitly, but will continue to work if the function is renamed via `fn.name`

---

Alternatively, if the function isn't an arrow function, you can also use `arguments.callee`, that will work even with anonymous functions, but its use isn't recommended:

```js
var A = function (n) {
  console.log(n + arguments.callee.num());
}
A.num = function() {
  return 5;
}

var B = A;
A = undefined;
B(10); //15
```

Unfortunately, none of the above will work with arrow functions, if you want to refer to itself, use a named bound function expression instead.

Answer (score 0):

actually that's normal, because in js you can't really copy object

```
// Define object bar
var bar = {
   x : 'Hi'
}
console.log(bar.x);  //Hi

// Assign it to foo
var foo = bar;
console.log(foo.x);  //Hi

//But
foo.x = 'Hello!! Im foo.';
console.log(foo.x);  //Hello!! Im foo.
console.log(bar.x);  //Hello!! Im foo.

bar.x = "Nice to meet you foo!!";
console.log(foo.x);  //Nice to meet you foo!!
console.log(bar.x);  //Nice to meet you foo!!
```

you have to return a new one with the same value as the last

```
var foo = {...bar};
```

and this is not working because B is always calling 'num' from A that doesn't exist, One way to sever the parity would be stringify the initial function, then use a function constructor to create the clone after replacing the 'A' by 'B' 
but tell me more why are you facing this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var A = function(n) {
  if(!this.num){
  console.log("This is not available coz obj is not created");
  console.log("Below error is for testing purpose");
  }
  let a=this.num(n);
  console.log(a);
}
//use prototype here 
//A.num = function() {
A.prototype.num=function(n){
  return n+5;
}
//use new to create object 
new A(5);
var B = A;
A = undefined;
//use new to create object 
new B(6);

B(5);//lets try without using new keyword
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```